# Нужна помощь дописать код на "Запрет ввод кириллицы а текстовое поле"

Tags: jquery, javascript, кириллица

Как написать JS скрипт, который не даст вводить в тестовое поле кириллицу? 
Т.е. когда я ввожу в поле: ВОВА то в поле должно показываться DJDF

Нужна помощь дописать код на  ["Запрет ввод кириллицы а текстовое поле"](http://jsfiddle.net/Hancock_888/6Sn8h/)

Comment: А если пользователь вводит символы других алфавитов? Например, ಠ_ಠ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделал как-то так, чтобы не заморачиваться с keycode и иметь возможность перехватывать вставку текста:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var charmap = {};
    var rus = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю".split('');
    var eng = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.".split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < rus.length; i++) {
        charmap[rus[i]] = eng[i];
    }

    function rustoeng(string) {
        return string.replace(/([^a-z\s])/gi,

        function (x) {
            return charmap[x] || x;
        });
    }

    $('.info_it').on('input keydown paste', function (e) {
        $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            var newval = rustoeng($this.val());
            if ($this.val() != newval) {
                //записать выделение и позицию курсора
                var caret = $this.caret();
                $this.val(newval);
                //восстановить
                $this.caret(caret);
            }
        }, 0);
    });

});
```

setTimeout задан чтобы символ точно появился в строке, так-же используется плагин jCaret,
[см. демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/L9gWJ/)

Answer (score 1):

"Как написать?" => пальцами и нужно использовать не Jquery, а [underscore.string](http://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/)

1. Разбить введенный текст на буквы
2. Создать объект с соответствующими ассоциациями
      й - q, ц - w, у - e и т.д.
3. И заменить побуквенно

Comment: ну и зачем тут underscore ?

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/r5ZSe/

Comment: Вообще все просто реализуется без всяких underscore.
тык[1]

[1] http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_keypress